# AJAX - Keeping linkable content within a DIV

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax, flash

I am currently responsible for maintaining my company`s internal knowledge base. The site uses flash navigation and ASP to pull content into a div in the middle of the page. I am redesigning the site and eliminating the use of flash and ASP for a bunch of reasons, one being that we need this resource to be available offline. So I have created static navigation and I am using AJAX to force content into the DIV. I realize that this is not best practice but we need some kind of navigation on every page and modifying hundreds maybe thousands of individual pages is not an option. Every thing I have done up until now is working great!

Here is the problem,

The pages that open inside the DIV have tons of links themselves. These links are opening in new pages and that just wont do. Every other page has to open inside that DIV. I don`t even know if this is possible but I would love to get an answer for this even if it is not best practice.

Thanks in advance for your replies,

Marty

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It provides a very easy to use method for event delegation, and that should fix your problem (given all those links are internal to your domain). Take a look at [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: He'd need to utilize jQuery to rewrite on every page, so he'd still need to do a global header rewrite.  AJAX isn't an option because of the need for this to run offline.

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike, are you sure? I'm thiking he's okay with ajax (already using it), and just wants to trap the click on anchors added after the DOM is ajax-updated. If that's what he's asking, delegation is the way to go. And no, jQuery only has to be included in the first page, the others will be injected directly inside some div.

Comment: No, you can't run AJAX from the file::// protocol.  He might be doing something off of a server now, but if he thinks that is going to translate to offline, it just isn't.  Since there's no AJAX, he has to load each file individually through some sort of frame.  Although he should be able to sniff out the frame's contents, that's generally unpredictable because of how the eventing works cross-window.  So again, recommendation would be to do a global header rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that without putting in A LOT of efforts is to open that page in an iframe.  You would add the iframe and you are done.Saying that, I must tell you that it's consider as a bad practice.

Your other option is to make changes to all those pages so that the link they are referring to, gets loaded within that div.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<base target="name-of-the-div-where-you-want-the-link-to=open">
```

in the head section and you should be good to go

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Would definitely like to see if this work in given scenario.

Comment: Won't really work for internal links.  And I believe what is required is the name of the *iframe*, not div.  Once you're in the Iframe context, the default _self target should work fine.

Comment: have it working on a page here , however will wait to see if he tries this

Comment: I'm just suggesting that it is unnecessary.

You define a page with an IFRAME (although I think Mozilla lets you specify a DIV, this would be a huge mistake, breaking just about everywhere else).  You define the SRC of that IFRAME internally in the page or externally through the navigation.  Once the content is in the context of the IFRAME, a BASE element is wholly unnecessary as the content inside the IFRAME will automatically target itself -- and any external navigation links (in the page header) would target the IFRAME as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot John for the clarification, will surely keep this in mind , when working in future.